# What does the moveBelow method of Control class do?

Tags: java, swt, controls, grid-layout

I am using a Gridlayout with 2 column. I have Labels and corresponding Text control with it. I wanted the Text control of first label to slip down the label instead of right next to it (since its a gridlayout). For this I thought the moveBelow method would work but doesn't seem to be. Am  i interpreting the use of the method wrongly?

```
Label label = Components.createLabel(myContainer, SWT.LEFT
                | SWT.WRAP);
        abel.setText("WC Plan Name");
        textName = createTextControl(myContainer, SWT.LEFT);
        textName.moveBelow(label);

private Text createTextControl(Composite parent, int horizontalAlignment)
    {
        final Text textControl = Components.createText(parent, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
        final GridData layoutData = new GridData(horizontalAlignment, SWT.FILL, false, false);
        layoutData.widthHint = 200;
        textControl.setLayoutData(layoutData);
        return textControl;
    }
```

Comment: Elaborate on `would work but doesn't seem to be` please. Thank you!

Comment: I meant the Text would come below the label but it does not. Instead it comes right next to the label.

Comment: May I see your code? :)

Comment: `moveBelow` sets the position in the 'Z order' which is used to control the order controls are drawn when they **overlap**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moveBelow()` does exactly what it says in the documentation:

> **Moves the receiver below the specified control in the drawing order**. If the argument is null, then the receiver is moved to the bottom of the drawing order. The control at the bottom of the drawing order will be covered by all other controls which occupy intersecting areas.

This means that it can be used to reorder children (if the layout of the parent allows it). For example, if you have a `RowLayout` and call `moveBelow(null)` on the last child, it will be moved to the top.

---

Now to solve your problem: You have a `GridLayout` with 2 columns. A `GridLayout` is filled from top left to bottom right. If you want two elements to appear below each other rather than next to each other, there are two options:

1. Add an empty `Label` in between, so that it can occupy the space to the right of your first element
2. Add a `GridData` to your first element and set `GridData#horizontalSpan` to `2`. This way it will span two columns.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of solution 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));

    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.TOP, false, true, 4, 1));

    text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, true, 4, 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button " + i);
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank You Baz. Won't the second option increase the size of text box? I don't want to use the first option because i am going to increase the number of columns in my Gridlayout to 4 since the next row contains 4 fields. Si I will have to put 3 empty labels

Comment: @Vwin That all depends on how you use your `GridData`. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: It worked. Thank you :D. I had one more doubt which is bugging my mind. If you see my question, I had written a createTextControl method for creating text control and setting the griddata. When I use that method and use the moveBelow method after getting the textControl to move it below the label, it doesn't work. But when dont use the method instead create and set the griddata there itself, the moveBelow seems to wok when I use it. Any idea what I am doing wrong. Even thought this is insignificant now after your sol^ but just had this in my mind

Comment: @Vwin I can't say without you posting the complete code with both examples, i.e., the one that works and the one that doesn't. The devil is in the detail.

Comment: I don't want to add it in the question because does not relate to it. :( How do you use chat here?